# Trying to add style on react toastify

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-toastify

I am trying to add custom style on react toastify, firstly I have import these

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

than call the react toast:

```
 const handleToast = () => {
        toast("sent mail")
    }
```

Here i adding css in toast container :

```
<div>
            <ToastContainer toastStyle={{
                marginTop: "4rem",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                backgroundColor: "red"
            }} />
            <button onClick={handleToast} className='btn btn-info'>Click here</button>
        </div >
```

But in ToastContainer component css not working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are we supposed to answer? Please provide a small codesandbox or clarify what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the styles to a root/global CSS file.
The classNames you'd use would mainly be:
`.Toastify`
`.Toastify__toast-container`
`.Toastify__progress-bar`
`.Toastify__toast`
`.Toastify__toast-body`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear to me.
I believe you want to style the toast itself. If so, you can easily do it by adding classes like this,

```
toast("Sent mail",{
      className: 'black-background',
      bodyClassName: "grow-font-size",
      progressClassName: 'fancy-progress-bar'
    });
```

You can add your preferred classnames on `global css` file, and apply your desired styles there. Here,

- className: applied on the toast wrapper (this override toastClassName is set by the container )
- bodyClassName: applied on the toast body (this override bodyClassName is set by the container )
- progressClassName: applied on the progress bar (this override progressClassName is set by the container )
- style: inline style applied to the toast

Also if you want to style the `ToastContainer`, you can do it the same way.

```
 <ToastContainer toastClassName="foo" style={{ width: "2000px" }} />
```

- toastClassName: applied on the toast wrapper

```
 <ToastContainer className="foo" style={{ width: "2000px" }} />
```

To know more about how to style it in a different way, you can check out there documentation on styling from here
[How to style](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style/)